# Why use Python's os module methods instead of executing shell commands directly?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I am trying to understand what is the motivation behind using Python's library functions for executing OS-specific tasks such as creating files/directories, changing file attributes, etc. instead of just executing those commands via `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`?

For example, why would I want to use `os.chmod` instead of doing `os.system("chmod...")`?

I understand that it is more "pythonic" to use Python's available library methods as much as possible instead of just executing shell commands directly. But, is there any other motivation behind doing this from a functionality point of view?

I am only talking about executing simple one-line shell commands here. When we need more control over the execution of the task, I understand that using `subprocess` module makes more sense, for example.

Comment: You basically hit the nail on the head.  The OS level tasks you refer to are common enough that they warranted their own function instead of just being relegated to being called via os.system.

Comment: BTW, did you try to time execution time - _os.chmod_ vs. _os.system("chmod...")_. I would hazard a guess that it will answer part of your question.

Comment: Why have `print` when you could `os.system("echo Hello world!")` ?

Comment: For the same reason you should use `os.path` to handle paths instead of manually handling them: it works on every OS where it runs.

Comment: "Executing shell commands directly" is actually *less* direct. The shell isn't a low-level interface to the system, and `os.chmod` isn't going to call the `chmod` program the shell would. Using `os.system('chmod ...')` launches a shell to interpret a string to call another executable to make a call to the C `chmod` function, while `os.chmod(...)` goes much more directly to the C `chmod`.

Comment: @user2357112: strictly speaking it doesn't necessarily go to C's chmod, but rather to chmod syscall. In CPython's case, it probably don't reimplement the local syscall convention but rather just reuse the C library's syscall convention implementation but other implementations might possibly decide differently.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

1. It's **faster**, `os.system` and `subprocess.call` create new processes which is unnecessary for something this simple. In fact, `os.system` and `subprocess.call` with the `shell` argument usually create at least two new processes: the first one being the shell, and the second one being the command that you're running (if it's not a shell built-in like `test`).
2. Some commands are **useless in a separate process**. For example, if you run `os.spawn("cd dir/")`, it will change the current working directory of the child process, but not of the Python process. You need to use `os.chdir` for that.
3. You don't have to worry about special **characters interpreted** by the shell. `os.chmod(path, mode)` will work no matter what the filename is, whereas `os.spawn("chmod 777 " + path)` will fail horribly if the filename is something like `; rm -rf ~`. (Note that you can work around this if you use `subprocess.call` without the `shell` argument.)
4. You don't have to worry about **filenames that begin with a dash**. `os.chmod("--quiet", mode)` will change the permissions of the file named `--quiet`, but `os.spawn("chmod 777 --quiet")` will fail, as `--quiet` is interpreted as an argument. This is true even for `subprocess.call(["chmod", "777", "--quiet"])`.
5. You have fewer **cross-platform** and cross-shell concerns, as Python's standard library is supposed to deal with that for you. Does your system have `chmod` command? Is it installed? Does it support the parameters that you expect it to support? The `os` module will try to be as cross-platform as possible and documents when that it's not possible.
6. If the command you're running has **output** that you care about, you need to parse it, which is trickier than it sounds, as you may forget about corner-cases (filenames with spaces, tabs and newlines in them), even when you don't care about portability.

Comment: To add to the "cross-platform" point, listing a directory is "ls" on linux, "dir" on windows.  Getting the contents of a directory is a very common low level task.

Comment: @CortAmmon: "Low-Level" is relative, `ls` or `dir` are pretty high level to certain types of developers, just as `bash` or `cmd` or `ksh` or whatever shell you prefer are.

Comment: @phresnel : I never thought about it that way.  To me, "direct call to your OS's kernel API" was very low level.  I'm assuming there is a different perspective on this that is eluding me because I am (naturally) approaching it with my own biases.

Comment: @CortAmmon: right, and `ls` is higher level than that, since it's not a direct call to your OS's kernel API. It's a (small) application.

Comment: @SteveJessop.  I called "getting the contents of a directory" low level.  I'm not thinking `ls` or `dir` but `opendir()/readdir()` (linux api) or `FindFirstFile()/FindNextFile()` (windows api) or `File.listFiles` (java API) or `Directory.GetFiles()` (C#).  All of these are closely tied to a direct call to the OS.  Some may be as simple as pushing a number into a register and calling `int 13h` to trigger kernel mode.

Comment: @CortAmmon: ah, ISWYM. I combined your remark about "listing a directory" with your remark about "getting the contents of a directory", assuming you meant to talk about the same thing in both cases. But now I realise presumably part of the point of that comment was to distinguish the two, not conflate them :-)

Comment: Frankly, I would put the *cross-platform* concern on top: `This module provides a portable way...` https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Answer (score 134):

It is safer. To give you an idea here is an example script

```
import os
file = raw_input("Please enter a file: ")
os.system("chmod 777 " + file)
```

If the input from the user was `test; rm -rf ~` this would then delete the home directory.

This is why it is safer to use the built in function.

Hence why you should use subprocess instead of system too.

Comment: Or another way to look at it, what's easier to get right, writing Python programs or writing Python programs that write shell scripts? :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, a colleague of mine was amazed that a small Python script I helped him write worked 20 (!) times faster tan shell script. I explained that output redirection may look sexy - but it entails opening and closing file on each iteration. But some love to do stuff the hard way -:)

Comment: @SteveJessop, this is a trick question -- you wouldn't know until runtime! :)

Answer (score 60):

There are four strong cases for preferring Python's more-specific methods in the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module over using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) or the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module when executing a command:

- **Redundancy** - spawning another process is redundant and wastes time and resources.
- **Portability** - Many of the methods in the `os` module are available in multiple platforms while many shell commands are os-specific.
- **Understanding the results** - Spawning a process to execute arbitrary commands forces you to parse the results from the output and understand **if** and **why** a command has done something wrong.
- **Safety** - A process can potentially execute any command it's given. This is a weak design and it can be avoided by using specific methods in the `os` module.

### Redundancy (see [*redundant code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundant_code)):

You're actually executing a redundant "middle-man" on your way to the eventual system calls (`chmod` in your example). This middle man is a new process or sub-shell.

From [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell ...

And [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is just a module to spawn new processes.

You can do what you need without spawning these processes.

### Portability (see [*source code portability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability#Source_code_portability)):

The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module's aim is to provide generic operating-system services and it's description starts with:

> This module provides a portable way of using operating system dependent functionality.

You can use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) on both windows and unix. Trying to use `os.system` / `subprocess` for this functionality will force you to maintain two calls (for `ls` / `dir`) and check what operating system you're on. This is not as portable and **will** cause even more frustration later on (see **Handling Output**).

### Understanding the command's results:

Suppose you want to list the files in a directory.

If you're using `os.system("ls")` / `subprocess.call(['ls'])`, you can only get the process's output back, which is basically a big string with the file names.

How can you tell a file with a space in it's name from two files?

What if you have no permission to list the files?

How should you map the data to python objects?

These are only off the top of my head, and while there are solutions to these problems - why solve again a problem that was solved for you?

This is an example of following the [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle (Often reffered to as "DRY") by **not** repeating an implementation that already exists and is freely available for you.

### Safety:

`os.system` and `subprocess` are powerful. It's good when you need this power, but it's dangerous when you don't. When you use `os.listdir`, you **know** it can not do anything else other then list files or raise an error. When you use `os.system` or `subprocess` to achieve the same behaviour you can potentially end up doing something you did not mean to do.

**Injection Safety (see [*shell injection examples*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection))**:

If you use input from the user as a new command you've basically given him a shell. This is much like SQL injection providing a shell in the DB for the user.

An example would be a command of the form:

```
# ... read some user input
os.system(user_input + " some continutation")
```

This can be easily exploited to run **any** arbitrary code using the input: `NASTY COMMAND;#` to create the eventual:

```
os.system("NASTY COMMAND; # some continuation")
```

There are many such commands that can put your system at risk.

Comment: I would say 2. is the main reason.

Answer (score 23):

For a simple reason  - when you call a shell function, it creates a sub-shell which is destroyed after your command exists, so if you change directory in a shell - it does not affect your environment in Python.

Besides, creating sub-shell is time consuming, so using OS commands directly will impact your performance

**EDIT**

I had some timing tests running:

```
In [379]: %timeit os.chmod('Documents/recipes.txt', 0755)
10000 loops, best of 3: 215 us per loop

In [380]: %timeit os.system('chmod 0755 Documents/recipes.txt')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.47 ms per loop

In [382]: %timeit call(['chmod', '0755', 'Documents/recipes.txt'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop
```

Internal function runs more than 10 time faster

**EDIT2**

There may be cases when invoking external executable may yield better results than Python packages - I just remembered a mail sent by a colleague of mine that  performance of *gzip* called through subprocess was much higher than the performance of a Python package he used. But certainly not when we are talking about standard OS packages emulating standard OS commands

Comment: By any chance is that done with iPython? Didn't think you could use special functions beginning with `%` using the normal interpreter.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper, yep, it was iPython - on Ubuntu. "Magical" _%timeit_ is a blessing - though there are some cases - mostly with string formatting - that it cannot process

Comment: Or you can also make a python script and then type `time <path to script>`  in terminal and it will tell you the real, user and process time taken. That is if you don't have iPython and you have access to the Unix command line.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper, I see no reason to work hard - when I have iPython on my machine

Comment: True! I did say if you didn't have iPython. :)

Answer (score 16):

Shell call are OS specific whereas Python os module functions are not, in most of the case. And it avoid spawning a subprocess.

Comment: Python module functions also spawn new subprocesses to invoke a new subshell.

Comment: @Koderok nonsense, module functions are called in-process

Comment: @Koderok: the os module uses the underlying system calls that the shell command used, it doesn't use the shell commands. This means the os system call are usually safer and faster (no string parsing, boo fork, no exec, instead it's just a kernel call) than the shell commands. Note that on most cases, the shell call and the system call often have similar or same name, but there documented separately; the shell call is in man section 1 (the default man section) while the equivalently named system call is in man section 2 (e.g. man 2 chmod).

Comment: @dwurf,LieRyan: My bad! I had a wrong notion, it seems. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It's far more efficient. The "shell" is just another OS binary which contains a lot of system calls. Why incur the overhead of creating the whole shell process just for that single system call?

The situation is even worse when you use `os.system` for something that's not a shell built-in. You start a shell process which in turn starts an executable which then (two processes away) makes the system call. At least `subprocess` would have removed the need for a shell intermediary process.

It's not specific to Python, this. `systemd` is such an improvement to Linux startup times for the same reason: it makes the necessary system calls itself instead of spawning a thousand shells.