# How can I deal with the " ' in os.system cmd command?

Tags: python, imagemagick

I am using python os.system to call imagemagick command to add some text to some images, codes are as below:

`os.system("convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white -pointsize 75 -draw \"text 50,100 \'thing\'\" C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\output.png")`,
 howerver, it did nothing.

Then i tried to delete the slashs in the string, but also nothing happened. It seems `os.system` is not good at quotation marks problems. But I think there should be a proper solution on these issues.

So can anyone do me a favor to analysis this command string?

Of course, in command line, it works well: `convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white -pointsize 75 -draw "text 50,100 'thing'" C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\output.png`

Comment: why are you escaping the double quotes? Only escape the single quotes `os.system('convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white -pointsize 75 -draw "text 50,100 \'thing\'" C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\output.png')`

Comment: Does the command work from the command line?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to create a complex string use triple quotes (either `"` or `'`) and the raw string prefix (`r`) which prevents interpreting of escape codes. In addition `subprocess` should be preferred over `os.system` for running commands. eg.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = r"""convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white 
    -pointsize 75 -draw  "text 50,100 'thing'" 
    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\output.png"""
retcode = subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd, posix=False))
```

`shlex` preserves everything between and including double quotes when `posix=False`. Maybe this isn't exactly what you want. If don't use `posix=False`, the single argument `"text 50,100 'thing'"` becomes the single argument `text 50,100 'thing'` (no double quotes). However, you will need to quote the file name to prevent it interpreting `\` as an escape character.

```
cmd = r"""convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white 
    -pointsize 75 -draw "text 50,100 'thing'" 
    'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\output.png'"""
retcode = subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Comment: Hi, it looks pretty promising!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python API for [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).

There is [good reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572833/why-use-pythons-os-module-methods-instead-of-executing-shell-commands-directly/28572898#28572898) behind why **not** to use `os.system` for such tasks when an API is available.

That said, I think the problem is escaping the single-quotes in `\'thing\'`, so maybe this will work:

```
os.system("convert -size 2048x2048 xc:transparent -point -fill white -pointsize 75 -draw \"text 50,100 'thing'\" C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\output.png")
```